Signing Manifest files using Azure Trusted Signing - with or without Mage.exe
The current documentation doesn't indicate that Mage.exe is yet supported by Azure Trusted Signing.
Does anyone know if it is possible to use Azure Trusted Signing with Mage yet? (the Mage documentation doesn't suggest this, but neither does the current SignTool documentation, no mention of the /dlib switch). If this is the correct source location, it doesn't look like Mage has been updated recently with any mention of supporting Azure Trusted Signing.
Does anyone know a way that we could sign the manifests with Azure Trusted Signing support without using Mage?

I ended up migrating off ClickOnce (this is classed as a workaround), and switched to deploy using Velopack. It was about a day's worth of effort to migrate off ClickOnce, and Velopack can use Trusted Signing as it uses signtool already and therefore supports Azure Trusted Signing. Velopack does everything I needed for the application, so this is a good, an permanent workaround. Goodbye ClickOnce.
